# I was trying to mutate a new numeric column in a dataframe but the compliler is taking it as char's and i am not even able to access it using index

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
library(dslabs)
data(heights)
library(dplyr)

mutate(heights, ht_cm = height * 2.54, stringsAsFactor = FALSE )

str(heights) # not showing ht_cm as a variable in the data frame

mean(heights$ht_cm) # giving error that argument is not numeric
```

Comment: You need to assign `heights <- mutate(heights, ht_cm = height * 2.54)` `stringsAsFactors` is an argument in `data.frame` and not in `mutate`

Answer (score 0):

You just used `mutate`, but if you want to add the new column in `height` you need to:

### Code

```
heights <-
  heights %>% 
  mutate(ht_cm = height * 2.54)
```

### Output

```
str(heights)

'data.frame':   1050 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ height: num  75 70 68 74 61 65 66 62 66 67 ...
 $ ht_cm : num  190 178 173 188 155 ...
```